# Magento 2 How to create cache for a collection inside controller

Tags: cache, controllers, caching

Hi am having a controller `Search.php` every time I do operation it loads all the collection and takes much time to load. So I wanted to cache the custom collection and optimize the loading time.
this is my collection how to put this in a cache.
below is my controller

```
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

class Search extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    private cacheId = 'IdForCachingPurposes';
    private $serializer;
    
    public function __construct(
        SerializerInterface $serializer,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->serializer   = $serializer;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PRAVEEN.log'); 
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger(); $logger->addWriter($writer); 

        $collection = "My data";
        if($this->cache->load($this->cacheId)) {
            $logger->info('cached'); 

            //Get unserialized data from Cache
            $data = unserialize($this->cache->load($this->cacheId));
        } else {
            $logger->info('cach saved'); 

            //Store Data in Cache
            $storeData = $this->cache->save(
            serialize($collection), $this->cacheId, array(\Vendor\Search\Model\Cache\Type::CACHE_TAG), 
            86400);
        }
    }
}
```

Where am doing wrong. Can I get Help?
Thank yo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code：

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Search extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $cache;

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->cache = $cache;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $cacheId = 'IdForCachingPurposes';
        $testData = "My data";

        if ($cacheData = $this->cache->load($cacheId)) {
            $cacheData = unserialize($cacheData);
            $this->logger->info('---Get Cache Data---');
            $this->logger->info($cacheData);
            return $cacheData;
        }
        $this->logger->info('---Save Cache Data---');
        $this->logger->info($testData);
        $this->cache->save(serialize($testData), $cacheId, [], 86400);
        return $testData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you So much @Tokey Tu, its working fine.

Comment: How do you clear the cacheId when the cache is cleaned?